# How to convert an epub package to regular epub?

Tags: books, epub

I have some epub files in my iCloud Drive that are essentially packages.  I can show package contents and then it shows me a hierarchy of files and folders.

How can I convert this structure to a standard epub that any regular epub reader will understand?

Comment: (this may be an answer) Have you tried directly inserting the ePub from your iCloud drive into your ePub reader?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that @Brick, however they show up as folders as noted above...

Comment: As in, does it properly display as intended in the reader?

Comment: No, they show up as a folder instead of a book. They simply give a folder hierarchy. I had figured that perhaps an epub folder would just need to be compressed and then renamed appropriately perhaps...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### How iBooks imports an ePub file:

A `.epub` file, as noted in other answers, is essentially a zipped up file. When **iBooks** imports the `.epub` file, the `.epub` file it stores is an **un**zipped file. This explains why it has the `Show Package Contents` option which lets you explore the "unzipped" files. However, just zipping the **package** doesn't always work.

#### Re-creating the `.epub` file from the **package**:

##### Manually:

1. <kbd>Right click</kbd> on the `.epub` file and click on `Show Package Contents`.
2. Select all the contents (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) → <kbd>Right click</kbd> → `Compress`.
3. This will create a `.zip` file. Simply change the extension from `.zip` to `.epub` and voila! The file has become an **ePub** document.

##### Automation:

I had more than **2,000** `.epub` **packages** I wanted to convert to `.epub` **files**, so the above method wasn't feasible. To avoid the manual labor, I wrote a script that essentially runs the above method on all the files. I used the simple and elegant [shell code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372808/437338) provided by Matthias here and wrapped it in a `python` script shared below:

```python
# Convert epub packages to epub files
import os
import subprocess

filenames = []
path_to_files = ""
#   Function to store all filenames in a list
def extract_filename(path_to_files):    # "/Users/****/Desktop/Old_epubs"
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
    books = os.getcwd()
    for f in os.listdir(books):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == ".epub":
            filenames.append(f_name)

    filenames.sort()

#   Function to generate new epub files
def create_epub(path_to_new_files): # "/Users/****/Desktop/new_epubs/"
    total_files = len(filenames)
    for i in range(total_files):
        epub_path = "cd " + path_to_files
        filename = filenames[i] + ".epub"
        zipping = " zip -X -r " + path_to_new_files + filename + " mimetype *"
        plist = "rm iTunesMetadata.plist"
        comm = epub_path + filename + "; " + plist + "; " + zipping
        p1 = subprocess.run(comm, capture_output = True, text = True, shell = True)
        success = p1.returncode
        if success == 0:
            rem_files = total_files - i + 1
            print("File #", i+1, " has been processed successfully. Remaining files: ", rem_files)

#   Enter the paths
extract_filename("/Users/****/Desktop/Books")   # Path to directory containing epub packages
create_epub("/Users/****/Desktop/new_epubs/")   # Path to store new epub files in
```

The `extract_filename` function takes a `path` to a directory that contains the `.epub` **packages** that need to be converted.
**[WARNING] It is best to work on a copy of the `.epub` packages in case something goes wrong.** To be safe, just copy the packages to a different directory and work on that.

The `create_epub` function takes a `path` to a directory where you want to store the generated files. It then runs a `shell` command to open each `.epub` **package** and generate a `.epub` **file**.

---

Hope this helps! It certainly solved a big headache of mine.

Answer (score 15):

FWIW, here's a shell command that works:

```
 cd my-broken.epub

 # iTunes/Books seems to add a file 
 # 'iTunesMetadata.plist', and it produces a warning.
 # May also contain private data, so better delete it.

 rm iTunesMetadata.plist 

 zip -X -r ../fixed.epub mimetype *
```

As far as I can tell, compression does not need to be deactivated (`-0`). `epubcheck` has no complaints. There might be differences between versions of the epub spec, however. My test was with an epub 3.0 file.

Comment: ✊ The Best ✊

Comment: This solution for me!

Comment: This worked for me! Out of curiosity, why remove `iTunesMetadata.plist`?

Comment: This is the way...

Comment: first ,I cannot `cd` to my broken epub until I find the name has empty space,use backslash to escape makes me `cd` successfully.

Answer (score 4):

An ePub file is essentially just a zipped folder, though it has a mimetype file inside which apparently needs to not be compressed.

This would imply that it's not completely straightforward to recreate with a simple zip app. However, it may be simpler than that.
Let's assume nothing has actually unpacked it, merely got confused about how to deal with it. Work on a copy.

Two things to try...

1. Try just renaming it, change .epub to .zip, then change it back again, see if it's recognised correctly.
2. Open it in [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com)
   You than have a myriad ways to deal with it, simplest is see if it can talk to your ebook reader via OPDS. Calibre can run its own local server on your wifi & you can copy books over very simply.
   If still no joy, get Calibre to convert it to an ePub [again] This is a great method for fixing a file, as it can re-examine it, fix fonts, bad hyphenations, all kinds of issues.

Calibre itself is too big a subject to really cover in a simple QA, but there are reams of data about it on the site itself & at http://www.mobileread.com/forums/ including sections for most major e-readers too.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.  I'm glad you confirmed my suspicion re: the compression.  Are you aware of any method to do this via the shell off the top? I'm assuming that this will be pretty quick and easy with a simple incantation if I can fiddle around and either find one or come up with one.

Comment: I did find this - http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=29057 - though I'm no expert when it comes to Terminal.

Comment: I know it's been 5 years, but just renaming .epub.zip to .epub fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Reproduction of the problem:**

1. A ePub file named, say, `book.epub` is a file (`-rw-r--r--`).
2. Open `book.epub` using iBooks app.
3. Take out the cached file stored in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books/`, which has been renamed to another name such as `A22DFAF7E75C21D979C375B1AD07008F.epub` and becomes a directory (`drwxr-xr-x@`).

**Steps of the work-around that works on my Mac:**

1. Change extension of `A22DFAF7E75C21D979C375B1AD07008F.epub` from `.epub` to `.zip`.
2. Go into the zip package and zip up all the contents inside into a new `.zip` file, say, `Archive.zip`.
3. Drag out the new `.zip` file and change extension back to `.epub`.
4. The `Archive.epub` file is a file (`-rw-r--r--`).

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted the methods shared here, and created the following shell script.

It's pretty simplistic as it does not take any arguments, it just runs from the directory it is executed in.
The script adds a `fixed` directory if there isn't one already, where it places the fixed files.

You can either add it to a file, i.e. `fix_epub.sh`. Or add it to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` etc. file, by wrapping it in a function. I've added examples for each below.

Then from your terminal, `cd <epub-path>` to your .epub folder and either;

1. Using the shell file  
   a. run `touch fix_epub.sh` and add your code to the file. 
   b. run `sh fix_epub.sh`.
2. Using a shell function  
   a. run `fix_epub` (assuming you've already added it to `.bashrc`).

---

### Scripts

`fix_epub.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p fixed

find . -name "*.epub" | while read -r file; do
  (cd "$file" || exit && \
  find . -iname 'iTunesMetadata*.plist' -delete && \
  zip -r -X "../fixed/$file" mimetype .)
done
```

`.bashrc`

```bsh
function fix_epub () {
  mkdir -p fixed

  find . -name "*.epub" | while read -r file; do
    (cd "$file" || exit && \
    find . -iname 'iTunesMetadata*.plist' -delete && \
    zip -r -X "../fixed/$file" mimetype .)
  done
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've taken some of the comments here and provided a [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jonmach/epubDirToFile) that does this for a backup of say a Books directory:

```
import pathlib
import glob
import os
import zipfile

# Extract the relevant components of a full path
def pathComponents(fullpath):
    path = pathlib.Path(fullpath)
    name = path.name
    stem = path.stem
    suffix = path.suffix
    parent = path.parent
    return name, stem, suffix, parent

# Get directories in your path that have a .epub suffix
def getePubDirs(path):
    epubSearch = os.path.join(path, "*" + "." + "epub")
    eDirs=[]
    for p in glob.glob(epubSearch):
        if (os.path.isdir(p)):    # Only if it's an epub directory
            eDirs.append(p)
    return eDirs

def createZipFile(fname, files):
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(fname, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for f in files:
        zFile.write(f)
    zFile.close()

def convertDirToePub(dirname):
    name, stem, suffix, parent = pathComponents(dirname)        # get dirname details
    newdirname = zFile = str(parent) + "/" + name + ".ori"
    zFile = str(parent) + "/" + stem + ".epub"
    os.rename(dirname,newdirname)     # rename the epub dir so the epub can take its old name
    # get all the files within the epub directory
    os.chdir(newdirname) # We need to be in directory so the resultant epub paths are correct
    everything = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk(".") for file in f]
    createZipFile(zFile, everything)  # Create a zip file containing all those files
    os.chdir(parent)

dirtoconvert='/Users/<username>/tmp/Booksdir'

eDirs = getePubDirs(dirtoconvert)
totalDirs=len(eDirs)
print(totalDirs, "docs to convert")
ctr=1
for i in eDirs:
    print(ctr, "of", totalDirs, ": Converting ", i)
    convertDirToePub(i)
    ctr = ctr + 1
print("Done!")
```