# Using a Python String on a Mac for a Non-Coder?

Tags: python, books, ebook

I'm thrilled to find Navddeep's solution here [How to convert an epub package to regular epub?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239050/how-to-convert-an-epub-package-to-regular-epub/429474#429474) yet two essential questions arise as I try to implement it.

1. What in the string must I change to identify my unique paths, or anything else?
2. How can I convert this string—not yet a py file—into something I can test and use as an executable? I'm driving Catalina on a MacBook Pro. I've worked in Mac IT for 20 years but I'm no coder and I'm certain Applescript hates me.The Python string is below.

```py
# Convert epub packages to epub files
import os
import subprocess

filenames = []
path_to_files = ""
#   Function to store all filenames in a list
def extract_filename(path_to_files):    # "/Users/****/Desktop/Old_epubs"
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
    books = os.getcwd()
    for f in os.listdir(books):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == ".epub":
            filenames.append(f_name)

    filenames.sort()

#   Function to generate new epub files
def create_epub(path_to_new_files): # "/Users/****/Desktop/new_epubs/"
    total_files = len(filenames)
    for i in range(total_files):
        epub_path = "cd " + path_to_files
        filename = filenames[i] + ".epub"
        zipping = " zip -X -r " + path_to_new_files + filename + " mimetype *"
        plist = "rm iTunesMetadata.plist"
        comm = epub_path + filename + "; " + plist + "; " + zipping
        p1 = subprocess.run(comm, capture_output = True, text = True, shell = True)
        success = p1.returncode
        if success == 0:
            rem_files = total_files - i + 1
            print("File #", i+1, " has been processed successfully. Remaining files: ", rem_files)

#   Enter the paths
extract_filename("/Users/****/Desktop/Books")   # Path to directory containing epub packages
create_epub("/Users/****/Desktop/new_epubs/")   # Path to store new epub files in
```

Answer (score 1):

The "string" is not a string. It is just text on a page as if you were reading a book.

The text if copied to a new file is a python program.

The steps are

1. Copy the text into a new file in a text editor e.g. TextEdit or nano
2. Save the file as convert.py or another filename ending in .py The suffix is the standard for python files.
3. Edit the last two lines to alter the paths for input directory and the output epub file respectively and save
4. In a Terminal change directory to the directory you saved the python file in.
5. In Terminal run `python convert.py` Or what ever you named the file as

I think this code works as python2 so will work with the Apple installed python - however if not you need a python3 and the easiest way is to install this via installing Xcode and its command line tools. You then need to run the command line as `python3 convert.py`

As a programming note I would not be using the subprocess.run to deletete things and zip the file. I would use that using python functions

The other answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372808/237 is probably easier to deal with. Just run the given command in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

regarding point 1:
it seems you should change `path_to_files = ""` to  `path_to_files = "path\to\your\folder\where\the\books\are"` and thats it

regarding point 2:
The simplest solution is to create a new text file, past the code into it and run `$ python new_file`
If you are reluctant to create a file, you can type in your terminal `python -c '`, then paste the text, and finally add another quote `'` mark and press enter

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else on a Mac needs to do this yet struggles with Python I found a much easier solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Calibre/comments/dza1zi/how_do_i_package_files_from_ibooks_own_files_not/). It's a little tedious for large libraries but it had my 1,300 titles sorted in a couple of hours with no frustrations.