# Looking for solution for bulk conversion of an epub packages to regular epubs

Tags: books, epub

I need a functional solution for bulk conversion of more than 2000 epub packages to regular epubs. I've been uploading books to the Books app on my mac to sort by author, as I have a lot of them, and I wanted to keep a bit of an overview. Then when I dragged it sorted like that into my Pocketbook it unfortunately turned into epub packages.

I found [How to convert an epub package to regular epub?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239050/how-to-convert-an-epub-package-to-regular-epub), unfortunately these suggested solutions don't work for me, it may be because working with Terminal is new to me.

So I would need code that I could just copy and possibly add only the path to the documents. Does anyone have something like this?

This is the copy of code in Terminal which I use:

```python
import os
import subprocess

filenames = []
path_to_files = ""
def extract_filename(path_to_files): "/Users/iveta/Desktop/řešit/Balíčky"                          
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
    books = os.getcwd()
    for f in os.listdir(books):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == ".epub":
            filenames.append(f_name)

    filenames.sort()

if function> def create_epub(path_to_new_files): "/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu"                      
    total_files = len(filenames)
    for i in range(total_files):
        epub_path = "cd " + path_to_files
        filename = filenames[i] + ".epub"
        zipping = " zip -X -r " + path_to_new_files + filename + " mimetype *"
        plist = "rm iTunesMetadata.plist"
        comm = epub_path + filename + "; " + plist + "; " + zipping
        p1 = subprocess.run(comm, capture_output = True, text = True, shell = True)
        success = p1.returncode
        if success == 0:
            rem_files = total_files - i + 1
            print("File #", i+1, " has been processed successfully. Remaining files: ", rem_files)

if if> extract_filename("/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu")              
create_epub("/Users/iveta/Desktop/loko")
if if>
```

the code I used:

```python
import os
import subprocess

filenames = []
path_to_files = ""
def extract_filename(path_to_files): "/Users/iveta/Desktop/řešit/Balíčky"
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
    books = os.getcwd()
    for f in os.listdir(books):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == ".epub":
            filenames.append(f_name)

    filenames.sort()


def create_epub(path_to_new_files): "/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu"
    total_files = len(filenames)
    for i in range(total_files):
        epub_path = "cd " + path_to_files
        filename = filenames[i] + ".epub"
        zipping = " zip -X -r " + path_to_new_files + filename + " mimetype *"
        plist = "rm iTunesMetadata.plist"
        comm = epub_path + filename + "; " + plist + "; " + zipping
        p1 = subprocess.run(comm, capture_output = True, text = True, shell = True)
        success = p1.returncode
        if success == 0:
            rem_files = total_files - i + 1
            print("File #", i+1, " has been processed successfully. Remaining files: ", rem_files)


extract_filename("/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu")              
create_epub("/Users/iveta/Desktop/loko")

OR


import os
import subprocess

filenames = []
path_to_files = ""
def extract_filename(path_to_files): 
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
    books = os.getcwd()
    for f in os.listdir(books):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if f_ext == ".epub":
            filenames.append(f_name)

    filenames.sort()


def create_epub(path_to_new_files):
    total_files = len(filenames)
    for i in range(total_files):
        epub_path = "cd " + path_to_files
        filename = filenames[i] + ".epub"
        zipping = " zip -X -r " + path_to_new_files + filename + " mimetype *"
        plist = "rm iTunesMetadata.plist"
        comm = epub_path + filename + "; " + plist + "; " + zipping
        p1 = subprocess.run(comm, capture_output = True, text = True, shell = True)
        success = p1.returncode
        if success == 0:
            rem_files = total_files - i + 1
            print("File #", i+1, " has been processed successfully. Remaining files: ", rem_files)


extract_filename("/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu")              
create_epub("/Users/iveta/Desktop/loko")
```

Comment: Are these epub packages all stored in the same directory, or could you move them all into one directory on your Mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please edit your question with a link to the thread you already followed, and if you can, add your attempt and the error it produced. There may be some use in looking at using [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com) to manage your ePubs, but it will become clearer if you can show the detail of what you've already tried.

Comment: Basically, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/429474/9058 does what you want to do. Once you have all the epubs in one directory, we can help you with the rest.

Comment: Yes, all packages are stored in the same directory and I can move them around. As for the apple.stackexchange.com/a/429474/9058 link, I tried it but I think I'm doing it wrong. I'm not much for terminal work. I'd need to distinguish more what I'm outputting and what I'm just copying. Otherwise, for working with a single package, the instructions worked for me, but since I have over 2000 of these books, I would need the bulk conversion to work.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm attaching a printscreen of my conversion attempt and I'll tell you right now, if you knock yourself in the forehead what I was able to create, I'm a beginner with terminal work. At the same time, thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, please copy/paste as text from Terminal and apply code formatting within the question.

Comment: Basically two things are required: The path to the directory containing the packages, and the path to the directory where the extracted epubs should be stored.

Comment: Hello. I have added the code copied from the terminal to the question.

Comment: Thanks (there seems to be something wrong in the last two lines). What happens if you run that script?

Comment: Precisely, nothing's gonna happen. It's just gonna show up "if if> or if function if if> "  and that's it. The file paths are correct, I checked that.

Comment: Ah, you just pasted this into a Terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you have a backup of the ePubs to be converted!**

- Open Terminal
- Type `cd ~/Desktop` and press Enter
- Switch to your browser, copy the code (and only the code) from [How to convert an epub package to regular epub?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239050/how-to-convert-an-epub-package-to-regular-epub/429474#429474) into the clipboard, switch back
- Type `pbpaste >convertepub.py` and press Enter
- Switch to Finder, locate `convertepub.py` on your Desktop, right-click on it and select "Open with -- Textedit"
- In Textedit, change the paths in the last two lines (the others are just comments), save and exit
- Back in Terminal, type `python3 ./convertepub.py` and press Enter.

Comment: Hello. I've tried it and I'm still not having much luck. First it threw me the message xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun, so I installed developer tools and now it says: File "/Users/iveta/Desktop/./convertepub.py", line 7
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
iveta@Iveta-iMac Desktop %

I put the code I used in the question because I couldn't put it in the comment because of the size. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @IvetaDrtinová We are getting there. On the lines starting with `def`, please remove the part **after** the `:`, then run the code again (last line in the answer).

Comment: Hello. I tried it. The top terminal bar said Desktop - zip<convertepub.py - 80x24 and an empty file called zignoZtS appeared on my desktop. That's it.

Comment: @IvetaDrtinová How long did you wait while the script was running? If you open `/Users/iveta/Desktop/loko`, is there anything in it?

Comment: Anyway, if it didn't work: Can you rename `/Users/iveta/Desktop/Bez názvu` into something without whitespace and special characters (e.g. `/Users/iveta/Desktop/source`) in Finder, change it in the script accordingly, and then try again to run it?

Comment: Hello, there was nothing in the loko folder and I left the script running for a while. On your advice I renamed the folder to something without spaces and punctuation and as a result nothing happens after I try again run it. I also tried typing in the path to def extract_filename(path_to_files) and def create_epub(path_to_new_files) to see if there was any response but it said this:
File "/Users/iveta/Desktop/./convertepub.py", line 7
    os.chdir(path_to_files)
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @IvetaDrtinová I'm running out of ideas, might need some support from somebody who can sit down with you in front of your Mac.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your efforts to help me, but I eventually found a program that compressed it into my desired epub format in a few minutes.

Comment: @IvetaDrtinová Great news! Can you post an answer explaining the solution which worked for you?

Comment: Sure. It was information in comment in question Using a Python String on a Mac for a Non-Coder? (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434497/using-a-python-string-on-a-mac-for-a-non-coder) on this website. Specially the comment from user Pamelane which refers to use a program  ePub Zip/Unzip AppleScript application for users which aren't good with Python or are beginners.